# DynamoDB and Python Docker Connection "Could not Connect"

Tags: python-3.x, docker, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamoDB instance running in docker using the following yml file.

```
    dynamodb:
        image: amazon/dynamodb-local
        hostname: dynamodb-local
        container_name: dynamodb-local
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
```

and I am trying to call it from another docker container with the following python code.

```
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb', endpoint_url='http://localhost:8000', region_name='anywhere')
```

When I run this is says `botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:8000/"`

What can I do to make this python code connect to the db instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like my issue was that I was assuming this would be exposed on port 8000 for localhost.
Instead it needed to be linked to the dynamo docker container.  In the yml file for the python docker compose I needed to add the following:

```
   links:
       - "dynamodb:db"
```

After that I could access via

```
ddb = boto3.client('dynamodb', endpoint_url='http://db:8000', region_name='anywhere')
```

Comment: You don't need `links:` at all in modern Docker; you can just use the other service's name `dynamodb` as a host name.  [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes the network environment in more detail.